# Passing 'StringVar()' to new window using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently trying to make a small application with a GUI that pulls weather from a website and displays the results in a window. I've got it to work without the GUI and also with the GUI but when I wrote the latter it was all in one script and not very organized. Because it was so unorganized, I decided to make make a separate script that would draw the GUI when the class was called.

Part of the GUI is an 'Entry' box that can be added via Tkinter. The entry box stores it's content into a StringVar() and that content can displayed using .get(). This works fine and well when I wrote everything unorganized into one script but I can't for the life of me figure out how to pass this StringVar() from one method to another in my program. This is what it looks like:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Forecast


class Frames(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def main_frame(self):
        main = Tk()
        main.title('WeatherMe')
        main.geometry('300x100')

        query = StringVar()

        Label(main, text='Enter a city below').pack()
        Entry(main, textvariable=query).pack()
        Button(main, text="Submit", command=self.result_frame).pack()

        main.mainloop()

    def result_frame(self):

        result = Tk()
        result.title('City')
        result.geometry('600x125')

        Button(result, text="OK", command=result.destroy).pack()


        result.mainloop()
```

Basically my goal is to have one window open when the program is launched with a label, an entry box, and a submit button. When a city is entered in the entry box and submit it clicked a new window will open displaying the results.

Because the entry is on the first window I need to pass the value of entry's StringVar() to the second window so it can then pull the data and display the labels. No matter what I try it doesn't seem to work, I either get a 404 error meaning something is wrong with that string making the link it tries to get a response from invalid or a concatenate error 'cannot concatenate str and instance objects'.

I've also tried saving StringVar() as a variable outside of either method but the issue with that is I need to then call another instance of Tk() before StringVar().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating two separate instances of `Tk`. You shouldn't do that. One reason why is because of this exact problem:  you can't share instances of widgets or tkinter variables between them.

If you need more than one window, create a single root window and then one or more instances of `Toplevel`. Also, call `mainloop` only for the root window.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Bryan! Everything is working fine now. I had no idea you couldn't share tkinter variables between two different instances. Appreciate the help!