# Not getting a value in the file when inputting details, its blank?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm relatively new to coding and to Stack Overflow. I am working on a game in tkinter for my school project. The part I am struggling with essentially takes the values input for regUser() and regPass(), and adds them to accountfile.txt. I initially got PYVAR0 and PYVAR1 but I saw online that using .get() would fix this. Now the space and /n are added but nothing for regUser or regPass is added.

This is all relating to register() and NOT login() (that will be done at a later date) but if anyone can spot issues that I might encounter when trying to check inputted values for username() and password () against saved names and passwords in the file, or indeed any advice on how to do this, that would be amazing. priority for the moment is fixing the current issue though :(.

Code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

def welcomeScreen():
    welcomeScreen = tk.Tk()
    welcomeScreen.title("Welcome")
    welcomeScreen.geometry("300x300")

    choice = tk.Label(text="Welcome to Investor, please log in or register an account")
    choice.pack()
   
    loginButton1 = tk.Button(welcomeScreen, text="Log in", command=lambda: [login(), welcomeScreen.destroy()])
    loginButton1.pack()
    regButton1 = tk.Button(welcomeScreen, text="Register", command=lambda: [register(), welcomeScreen.destroy()])
    regButton1.pack()
    welcomeScreen.mainloop()

def login():
    global username; tk.StringVar()
    global password; tk.StringVar()
    loginScreen = tk.Tk()
    loginScreen.geometry("400x300")
    loginScreen.title("Log in to your account")
    login1 = tk.Label(loginScreen, text="Please log in to your account")
    login1.pack()
   
    signIn = ttk.Frame(loginScreen)
    signIn.pack()
   
    lbl_username = ttk.Label(signIn, text="Username:")
    lbl_username.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

    entry_username = Entry(signIn, textvariable=username)
    entry_username.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
    entry_username.focus()

    lbl_password = ttk.Label(signIn, text="Password:")
    lbl_password.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

    entry_password = ttk.Entry(signIn, textvariable=password, show="*")
    entry_password.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

    btn_login = Button(signIn, text="Login", command=login)
    btn_login.pack()
    btn_back1 = Button(signIn, text="Back", command=lambda: [loginScreen.destroy(), welcomeScreen()])
    btn_back1.pack()

def register():
    global regUser
    regUser=tk.StringVar()
    global regPass
    regPass=tk.StringVar()

    regScreen = tk.Tk()
    regScreen.geometry("400x300")
    regScreen.title("regsiter")
    register1 = tk.Label(regScreen, text="Please create a account")
    register1.pack()
   
    register = ttk.Frame(regScreen)
    register.pack()
   
    lbl_createName = ttk.Label(register, text="Create an username:")
    lbl_createName.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

    entry_createName = Entry(register, textvariable=regUser)
    entry_createName.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
    entry_createName.focus()

    lbl_createPass = ttk.Label(register, text="Create an password:")
    lbl_createPass.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

    entry_createPass = ttk.Entry(register, textvariable=regPass)
    entry_createPass.pack(fill='x', expand=True)

    btn_reg = Button (register, text='Register', command=createUser)
    btn_reg.pack()
    btn_back2= Button(register, text="Back", command=lambda: [regScreen.destroy(), welcomeScreen()])
    btn_back2.pack()

def createUser():
    file = open("accountfile.txt","a")
    file.write(str(regUser.get()))
    file.write(" ")
    file.write(str(regPass.get()))
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()    
   
welcomeScreen()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: FYI, the first two lines of `login` are wrong.  You need to use the same pattern you used in `register`.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `global username; tk.StringVar()`, exactly what do you think this means? "This is all relating to register() and NOT login() (that will be done at a later date)" - then why are you showing us the code for `login`, or the code to make the login button?

Comment: The main problem is that you have 2 `tk.Tk` windows but you don't pass in a master for the `StringVar`s. Either use `tk.Toplevel` for all windows that aren't the main one (might be complicated in your case), add `master=...` to all `tk.StringVar`s so that they know which `tk.Tk` they belong to, or swap `[register(), welcomeScreen.destroy()]` => `[welcomeScreen.destroy(), register()]` but this will leave you with a similar problem for the log in page.

Comment: @JohnGordon Perhaps you missed the `textvariable` parameter on his `Entry` controls.  That's what updates those variables.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for your comment. This is an oversight on my part, I thought I had changed this to be in the same pattern as what is used on register(). As for why I am showing the login code. I am concerned that I will find a similar issue when I come to that, just wanted my concerns confirmed or not. My apologies if this isn't the right place for that type of question.

Comment: The idea on Stack Overflow is that you edit the example down to the part that specifically pertains to what you think the problem is, ask a clear, specific question, then try to make that example work following whatever answer you get. Then you try to adapt that back into the original context. If you have a new issue at that point, then you can consider asking a new question, after going through the same cycle of research (look for a duplicate, figure out *specifically* what the problem is *this* time, etc.) This is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: On close examination, and after reading the answer that was given so far, I think this is a duplicate of [Passing 'StringVar()' to new window using Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385938). The underlying problem is the same (creating multiple `tk.Tk` instances that exist sequentially). Part of the reason we ask for an MRE is that this time it could have helped find the problem. For example, if you tried making an example that started with the registration screen directly, I think it would have *worked* - which would be an important clue.

Answer (score 0):

The subtle problem here is that a StringVar must be associated with a window.  If you don't specify one, it defaults to the current root window, which is the `welcomeScreen`, which you destroy shortly after you create the new window.  So, those variables become "homeless".  Do this:

```
def register():
    global regUser
    global regPass

    regScreen = tk.Tk()
    regScreen.geometry("400x300")
    regScreen.title("regsiter")
    register1 = tk.Label(regScreen, text="Please create an account")
    register1.pack()

    register = ttk.Frame(regScreen)
    register.pack()

    regUser = tk.StringVar(register)
    regPass = tk.StringVar(register)
```

You'll need the same thing in the `login` function.